Why does my Snake Game in Java stop whenever i press 2 buttons at once?
I am a Java beginner and am working on a snake game. So far it runs okay, but whenever I press 2 buttons or more at the simultaneously, it automatically ends the game without the snake having any collision with itself or the wall whatsoever. Can anyone help me here please?
Here is my code, I am working with the CodeDraw package
import codedraw.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class SnakeGame {

    static final int canvasWidth = 800;
    static final int canvasHeight = 800;
    private final CodeDraw myDrawObj;
    static final int blockSize = 25;
    static final int totalBlockSpaces = (canvasWidth * canvasHeight) / (blockSize * blockSize);
    static final int snakeSpeed = 120;
    private final int[] x = new int[totalBlockSpaces];
    private final int[] y = new int[totalBlockSpaces];
    private int snakeLength = 3;
    int foodEaten;
    private double foodX;
    private double foodY;
    private String direction = "RIGHT";
    private final Random random;
    private boolean running = true;

    public SnakeGame() {
        myDrawObj = new CodeDraw(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        myDrawObj.setTitle("Snake Game");

        int[] positions = windowPosition();
        myDrawObj.setWindowPositionX(positions[0]);
        myDrawObj.setWindowPositionY(positions[1]);

        random = new Random();
        initializeGame();
    }

    public void initializeGame() {
        // if button pressed, start game
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; i++) {
            x[i] = canvasWidth / 4 - i * blockSize;
            y[i] = canvasHeight / 2;
        }
        food();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
        game.gameLoop();
    }

    public void gameLoop() {
        while (running) {
            handleKeyEvents();
            move();
            checkEat();
            checkImpact();
            drawSnake();
            myDrawObj.show(snakeSpeed);
        }
        gameOver();
    }
    
    private void handleKeyEvents() {
        EventScanner eventScanner = myDrawObj.getEventScanner();

        // Process all available events
        while (true) {
            try {
                Event event = eventScanner.nextEvent();

                if (event instanceof KeyDownEvent) {
                    onKeyDown((KeyDownEvent) event);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] windowPosition() {
        int screenWidth = 1920;
        int screenHeight = 1080;
        int windowPositionX = (screenWidth - canvasWidth) / 2;
        int windowPositionY = (screenHeight - canvasHeight) / 2;
        return new int[]{windowPositionX, windowPositionY};
    }

    public void food() {
        foodX = random.nextInt(canvasWidth / blockSize) * blockSize;
        foodY = random.nextInt(canvasHeight / blockSize) * blockSize;
    }

    public void checkEat() {
        if ((x[0] == foodX) && (y[0] == foodY)) {
            snakeLength++;
            foodEaten++;
            food();
        }
    }

    public void checkImpact() {
        for (int i = snakeLength; i > 0; i--) {
            if ((x[0] == x[i]) && (y[0] == y[i])) {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (x[0] < 0 || x[0] >= canvasWidth - 1 || y[0] < 0 || y[0] >= canvasHeight - 1) {
            running = false;
        }

        if (!running) {
            myDrawObj.clear();
            myDrawObj.setColor(Palette.RED);
            myDrawObj.drawText((double) canvasWidth / 2, (double) canvasHeight / 2, "GAME OVER");
        }
    }

    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
        switch (event.getKey()) {
            case UP:
                if (!direction.equals("DOWN")) direction = "UP";
                break;
            case LEFT:
                if (!direction.equals("RIGHT")) direction = "LEFT";
                break;
            case DOWN:
                if (!direction.equals("UP")) direction = "DOWN";
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                if (!direction.equals("LEFT")) direction = "RIGHT";
                break;
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        for (int i = snakeLength; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }

        switch (direction) {
            case "UP":
                y[0] -= blockSize;
                break;
            case "LEFT":
                x[0] -= blockSize;
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                y[0] += blockSize;
                break;
            case "RIGHT":
                x[0] += blockSize;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void startingScreen() {
        // TODO: starting screen with button that is checked in initializeGame method
        // TODO: high score display
        // TODO: mode selector: slow (snake speed 120), normal (snake speed 80), fast (snake speed 50)
    }

    public void gameOver() {

        int initialWidth = 400;
        int initialHeight = 650;
        int numRectangles = 3;
        double x = (double) canvasWidth / 4;
        double y = canvasHeight / 10.8;

        for (int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++) {

            double width = initialWidth + (i * 20);
            double height = initialHeight - (i * 11);

            double adjustedX = x - (width - initialWidth) / 2;

            myDrawObj.fillRectangle(adjustedX, y, width, height);

            // Update y position for the next rectangle
            y += 5;
        }

        String gameOver = "GAME OVER";

        int adjustedX = (canvasWidth / 2) - (gameOver.length() * 10) / 2;

        myDrawObj.setColor(Palette.OLIVE_DRAB);
        myDrawObj.drawText(adjustedX, (double) canvasHeight / 3.5, "GAME OVER!");
        myDrawObj.drawText(adjustedX, (double) canvasHeight / 2.5, "PLAY AGAIN");

        myDrawObj.drawText(adjustedX, (double) canvasHeight / 2.1, "YES");
        myDrawObj.drawText(adjustedX + ((double) initialHeight / 10), (double) canvasHeight / 2.1, "NO"); //TODO: selector here

        myDrawObj.drawText(adjustedX - 10, (double) canvasHeight / 1.3, "SCORE: "); //TODO: score here


        myDrawObj.show();
    }

    public void drawSnake() {
        myDrawObj.clear(Palette.OLIVE_DRAB);

        myDrawObj.setColor(Palette.DARK_RED);
        myDrawObj.fillSquare(foodX, foodY, blockSize);

        myDrawObj.setColor(Palette.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; i++) {
            myDrawObj.fillRectangle(x[i], y[i], blockSize, blockSize);
        }
    }
}

I've had a lot of problems with the handleKeyEvents method, particularly getting the snake to change directions when a button is pressed. My guess is that I've made some mistakes in this area. Additionally, I don’t display any error messages in my try-catch block because whenever I print an error message in catch (Exception e) {}, it floods the console. This might also be contributing to the game's premature finish when 2 buttons are pressed at the same time.
Any help is appreciated!
